Git clone stuck from Jenkins pipeline
I am trying to use git commands to clone a repository within the directory of a Jenkins build
I have ssh keys stored as credentials in my Jenkns job configuration, what i try: 
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'my-creds', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY')]) { sh 'export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i $SSH_KEY"' sh 'git clone --verbose --progress ssh://my-host/proj/proj.git' }
Unfortunatelly it hangs at:
Cloning into proj....

Any suggestions?
I know i could achieve this with the Git plugin:
git branch: 'master'
    url: 'ssh://my-host/proj/proj.git'
    credentials: 'my-creds'

But there are other operations i would like to perform after the checkout, therefore i would like to have the freedom to use git in the CLI way and not via the Jenkins plugin.

You can use the git plugin and still perform additional operations via 'sh' afterwards. Or add ssh -v -i $SSH_KEY to possibly get more verbose information on what's going wrong. And/or add -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no. This will automatically add the host key to your known_hosts file, which is probably not there yet.

Hi @Simon i will add the -v flag to ssh command, but for the other things you mentioned, could you please provide some examples? Maybe in an answer i stead of a comment?

Added 2 examples below. I could not reproduce your issue of a hanging git clone though. Only error because of git host not in known_host when using the git command.  With the git plugin it works even easier.

This works for a git repo on Bitbucket over SSH, but should also work on github/gitlab.
my-creds being a SSH Username with Private Key credential, for which you've added the public key to your git provider.

Using the Git plugin

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Clone Repository') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'my-creds', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY')]) {
                    git credentialsId: 'my-creds',
                        url: 'git@bitbucket.org:my-org/myrepo.git',
                        branch: 'master'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



Using git commands. Make sure to add remote SSH host key to your known_hosts (ssh-keyscan). Otherwise git clone will fail.

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Clone Repository') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'my-creds', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY')]) {
                    sh '''
                        ssh-keyscan -t rsa bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
                        export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v -i $SSH_KEY"
                        git clone --verbose --progress git@bitbucket.org:my-org/myrepo.git
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

(Instead of ssh-keyscan you can also add -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no to GIT_SSH_COMMAND, but this is not such a good idea from security perspective as it will just trust any host in this case.

-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no is what in needed!

The ssh-keyscan -t rsa <your_git_host> should have done the trick as well. Not for you?

Unfortunatelly not, i dont run this in Master node and it complains that ‘/.ssh/known_hosts’ does not exists

Ok, for completeness, the .ssh directory itself does not exist on the Jenkins slave node. So you can either add this to your Jenkins node template image, or add mkdir -p ~/.ssh before the ssh-keyscan command. (-p will create the directory if it does not exist, but skip instead of error when it already exists).
